# Eligibility trace and the role of gamma and lambda

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

From R.Sutton's book, the eligibility trace update rule is:
$$
E_t(s)\leftarrow\gamma~\lambda~ E_{t-1}(s)+\mathbb{1}(S_t=s)
$$
I wonder why do we need both $\gamma$ and $\lambda$ to assign credit to most recent states.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_discounting

Answer (score 1):

At least for gamma I can answer it generally without looking in the book:

Gamma is commonly used as the discount factor. That is a number in (0, 1) which defines how much of the reward you got in step i will be also given to step (i - n). Commonly, the reward is discounted exponentially (like gamma^n)

Answer (score 0):

I was also wondering that, I think I understand it, but I'm having a difficult time proving it.

The principle of using eligibility is that over a large sum you get the same result going backward as you would if you went forward (but you get the additional bonus of being able to update online).

Concerning λ: You use λ the same way as with the forward looking TD(λ) - as a exponential coefficient in a geometric series .

Concerning γ : Looking at the expression for the change in value:
$$
 \delta_t(s) = R_{t+1} + \gamma*V_t(s_{t+1}) - V_t(s_t)
$$
and 
$$
 V_{t+1}(s) = V_t(s) + \alpha* \delta_{t+1}*e_{t+1}(s)
$$
And you do that for EVERY step at EVERY time step, but there's no discount in δ nor in V. So, the future rewards get a discount only if γ is included in the E[s].

I'm also pretty sure that it makes all the other expressions cancel each other out in the sum (except for the rewards and the latest V[s]) , because for #lambda = 1 this should be the same as Monte Carlo:

$$
(\lambda = 1): V_{t+1}(s) = V_t(s) + \alpha* \delta_{t+1}*e_{t+1}(s)=V_t(s) + \alpha* \Sigma \gamma^nR_{n}(s)
$$

But I can't prove that yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was also thinking about this and eventually understood it this way:

Gamma is a parameter of the environment the agent is operating in (yes we can change it, but policies can only be evaluated and improved in relation to a single value of gamma).

In order for the backwards update to accurately reflect the amount of reward that a previous state will will be able to reach in the future, that reward must be discounted my gamma the appropriate number of times to accurately reflect the environment.

Lambda is used to determine how easily a signal from the current state can propagate backwards through previous states.

Essentially gamma determines how quickly reward decays, and lambda determines how quickly credit decays. We need to use both to determine how much to attenuate the reward signal we send backwards in time.